# Is there a way to create a detached BYOBU session on system boot?

Tags: boot, screen, systemd, byobu, tmux

First off - Thank you Dustin for creating such an amazing wrapper to TMUX. I have used TMUX for years, but this really brings things to the next level.

OK, I am using BYOBU in order to monitor and maintain a bunch of screens related to cryptomining. It's working great so far

Here is a sample window file I am using

```
new -s mining -c /home/prospector/mining ./run.sh;
renamew -t0 dstm ;
splitw watch -n1 nvidia-smi ;
splitw -t0 tail -f /home/prospector/mining/logs/dstm.log ;
```

This works great. Now, I want to be able to spawn this at startup. I tried adding a detach keyword from tmux in this file and adding it to a systemd start script, but after a lot of messing around, I just can't figure how to get it to start up

Here is my latest attempt at the systemd script

```
[Unit]
Description=BYOBU Session with miner
After=network.target default.target

[Service]
Environment=BYOBU_WINDOWS=mining
Environment=HOME=/home/prospector
Environment=TERM=xterm-256color
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/byobu'
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=prospector
Group=prospector

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When this starts up though, I see

> Unit miner.service has begun starting up.
>   Dec 21 09:58:41 prospector bash[1062]: open terminal failed: not a terminal
>   Dec 21 09:58:41 prospector systemd[1]: miner.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>   Dec 21 09:58:41 prospector systemd[1]: Failed to start BYOBU Session with miner.

My next attempt was to try to start a tmux server in detached mode and source my BYOBU file (this actually kind of works), but then when BYOBU starts up later and sees the session, it loads as regular tmux session...and doesn't add the nice BYOBU customization

Thanks to anyone that can assist!

Answer (score 0):

You can issue commands to Byobu's backend (tmux or screen) when launching it.

Using *screen*

```
byobu-screen -d -m ping google.com
```

Using *tmux*

```
byobu-tmux new-session -d -m ping google.com
# If tmux is default backend
byobu new-session -d -m ping google.com
```